# Bind data.table with diff rows such that the shorter dataset repeats the last row

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to bind two dataset in R with diff nrows such that the shorter dataset repeats the last row till equal length of other dataset grouped by the 'BY' variable

Suppose below are the two datasets

```
dt1<- data.table(Student = c(6,6,6,7,7),

            RollNum1 = c(49,69,44,86,39),

            Marks1= c(8,9,10,8,5))

dt2<- data.table(Student = c(6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7),

             RollNum2 = c(58,69,45,38,88,73,33,99,29,58,31,55,58,44,56,89),

             Marks2= c(8,9,10,3,5,7,8,8,9,6,9,5,9,3,4,8))
```

The merge should give the below result

```
Student   RollNum1  Marks1  RollNum2  marks2
6   49    8   58  8
6   69    9   69  9
6   44    10    45  10
6   44    10    38  3
6   44    10    88  5
6   44    10    73  7
6   44    10    33  8
6   44    10    99  8
6   44    10    29  9
7   86    8   58  6
7   39    5   31  9
7   39    5   55  5
7   39    5   58  9
7   39    5   44  3
7   39    5   56  4
7   39    5   89  8
```

I was able to get it for a single student value from another post but I am not sure how to group by student and run this and then append to get the final result.

To run for a single student value e.x - 6 : below is the code.

```
LastRowrep<-as.data.frame(matrix(rep(unlist(dt1[nrow(dt1),]),times=nrow(dt2)-nrow(dt1)),ncol = ncol(dt1), byrow = T))

colnames(LastRowrep)<-colnames(dt1)

cbind(rbind(dt1,LastRowrep),dt2)
```

But running this for different student values doesn't bind by group value

Comment: Thanks to Carles for first bit! I am still confused on how to get it for different student values.

Answer (score 3):

An other data.table approach using melting and casting. 
After casting, fill in NA's with locf. In the development-version of data.table, an `nafill` is implemented, but I';m using the `zoo::na.locf` until 1.12.3 goes final

```
DT <- rbind( melt(dt1, id.vars = "Student"), melt(dt2, id.vars = "Student") )[, rowid := rowid( Student, variable )]
ans <- dcast( DT, rowid + Student ~ variable, value.var = "value" )
setorder( ans, Student)
zoo::na.locf(ans, na.rm=FALSE)[, rowid := NULL][]

#    Student RollNum1 Marks1 RollNum2 Marks2
# 1:       6       49      8       58      8
# 2:       6       69      9       69      9
# 3:       6       44     10       45     10
# 4:       6       44     10       38      3
# 5:       6       44     10       88      5
# 6:       6       44     10       73      7
# 7:       6       44     10       33      8
# 8:       6       44     10       99      8
# 9:       6       44     10       29      9
#10:       7       86      8       58      6
#11:       7       39      5       31      9
#12:       7       39      5       55      5
#13:       7       39      5       58      9
#14:       7       39      5       44      3
#15:       7       39      5       56      4
#16:       7       39      5       89      8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dt1[, nrows := dt2[, .(rows = .N), by = Student][.SD, on = "Student", rows]]
dt1 <- dt1[, .SD[c(1:.N, rep(.N, nrows[1] - .N))], by = Student]
cbind(dt1[, !"nrows"], dt2[, !"Student"])

#     Student RollNum1 Marks1 RollNum2 Marks2
#  1:       6       49      8       58      8
#  2:       6       69      9       69      9
#  3:       6       44     10       45     10
#  4:       6       44     10       38      3
#  5:       6       44     10       88      5
#  6:       6       44     10       73      7
#  7:       6       44     10       33      8
#  8:       6       44     10       99      8
#  9:       6       44     10       29      9
# 10:       7       86      8       58      6
# 11:       7       39      5       31      9
# 12:       7       39      5       55      5
# 13:       7       39      5       58      9
# 14:       7       39      5       44      3
# 15:       7       39      5       56      4
# 16:       7       39      5       89      8
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want dplyr approach, here it is.

```
library(tidyverse)
dt1 = dt1 %>% gather(key, value, -Student)
dt2 = dt2 %>% gather(key, value, -Student)

dt3 = bind_rows(dt1, dt2) %>% 
  group_by(Student, key) %>% 
  mutate(id = seq(n())) %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  fill(c(Marks1:RollNum2)) %>% 
  select(-id)
```